# Relationship between Stack Overflow reputation and Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: discussion, reputation, stack-overflow-jobs

Does a user's reputation have any effect on jobs that user applies for on the Careers site?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/20407/will-high-reputation-in-stack-overflow-help-to-get-a-good-job http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30836/i-was-recently-asked-for-my-stack-overflow-reputation-score-in-a-job-interview/30839

Comment: What *kind* of effects are you thinking it might have?  There are many possibilities, some from the employer's side (do they see my rep?) to the application side (Do I have X rep in tag Y to apply for jobs with tag Y?)  Some hint of what you're thinking about would be nice.